# strapi v4 user register validation issue

Tags: authentication, graphql, strapi

I'm trying to setup user registration in my NextJS App with GraphQL mutations and it works (return the correct data with the jwt) but the password and username validation doesn't, in the schema.json file of the user-permissions plugin the minLength properties are set like this:

```
"username": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 3,
      "unique": true,
      "configurable": false,
      "required": true
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "email",
      "minLength": 6,
      "configurable": false,
      "required": true
    },
    "provider": {
      "type": "string",
      "configurable": false
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "password",
      "minLength": 6,
      "configurable": false,
      "private": true
    },
```

but in the frontend I am able to register a user with username and password that are less than the minLength value, maybe I need to add my own custom validation for those fields ? if yes how can I achieve that ?

I'm using Strapi v4

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the validation schema directly in the user-permissions plugin https://github.com/strapi/strapi/tree/master/packages/plugins/users-permissions()

You can look at the strapi docs to help you extend a plugin : https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins-extension.html#extending-a-plugin-s-content-types

You rewrite the register function in the **server/controllers/auth.js** file, and modify **registerBodySchema** in **server/controllers/validation/auth.js** with your own rules.

Finally, to integrate the function, in the **strapi-server.js** file like this:

```
const { controllers, routes, services } = require('./server')


module.exports = async (plugin) => {
   // Controllers
   plugin.controllers.auth.register = controllers.auth.register

   return plugin
}
```